# android swipe to delete list row

Tags: android, list, dynamic, swipe

so i've done some searching but haven't found a good answer. anyone who's familiar with android 4.0 knows the fancy swipe to remove running apps. i'm trying to implement this into a dynamic list.

when i say dynamic, it's a list being built with a base adapter and holder's.

i'm wondering if anyone has a good example of how to implement this swipe feature into a dynamic list. i want it to have the fancy animation and everything of the list collapsing back together after an element is removed. but, for now, i'm looking for a good starting point on how to properly implement this.

any and all help is always appreciated. thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

[SwipeListView](https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview) is an excellent ListView extension that does this. A demo application is also available on Google Play here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fortysevendeg.android.swipelistview

Comment: github link has gone!