# How to remove items from a list with swipe gesture like in gmail

Tags: android, list, swipe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [android swipe to delete list row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040895/android-swipe-to-delete-list-row)

I want to implement a list of items and on swiping left->right the item should be remove, like a Gmail. Has Android some native Elements to develop such list?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040895/android-swipe-to-delete-list-row

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No native api direct from android, but here is third level api "drag-sort-listview" that extendes the default listview

https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview

and the api has a remove option on swipe gesture.

Answer (score 15):

Roman Nurik posted some beta code implementing this feature a couple of months ago. Caveat is that it's only compatible for ICS+ devices. Fortunately, Jake Wharton backported the code soon after publication, using the NineOldAndroids library.

- [**BETA** Android 4.0-style "Swipe to Dismiss" sample code](https://gist.github.com/2980593)
- [Backport of Roman Nurik's "Swipe-to-dismiss" sample code using NineOldAndroids to work on all API levels](https://github.com/JakeWharton/SwipeToDismissNOA)

The latter provides a sample APK too, in case you feel like having a play with the result first.

Comment: Jake Wharton is legend !

Comment: 47deg also released a sample project and library based on Roman Nurik's work: https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview-sample#readme

Answer (score 0):

There is no native code to do that. 
However, you can check Roman Nurik's sample code [here](https://gist.github.com/2980593). Google Plus post [here](https://plus.google.com/113735310430199015092/posts/Fgo1p5uWZLu)