# How to implement gmail like Achieve or Undo action in a list item

Tags: android, android-listview, gmail, uiswipegesturerecognizer, swipe-gesture

I need to implement gmail like swipe action on a list item in my listview.
I am able to implement swipe on the list item, but how can remove the existing view and change to another view.How can I Archieve my message similar to gmail ?
Please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know much about android programming, but while browsing the web for a similar issue, I saw two other questions which may be of some interest for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14129005/android-how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-with-swipe-gesture-like-in-gmail and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040895/android-swipe-to-delete-list-row.